# Alternatives to chkrootkit for root kit checking?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I am currently using [chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org) to check for rootkits on my MacBook. Does anyone know of a more efficient piece of software to run rootkit checks on MacBooks and macOS?

Comment: How would you define "more efficient"? Generally questions which elicit opinion-based answers are often marked as such by the community.

Comment: I mean the absolute best odds of finding/locating a rootkit in the system. I don't think that is very opinion based.

Comment: What other root kit tools have you tried and what did you dislike about them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scan a Mac for rootkits and other stealthy security hazards](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136269/how-to-scan-a-mac-for-rootkits-and-other-stealthy-security-hazards) or [How to detect spy/keylogger software?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58727/how-to-detect-spy-keylogger-software/58759)

Comment: For what it's worth, `chkrootkit` is essentially useless on macOS. There is only one macOS agent which it has ever detected (OSX.RSPlug.A) -- which isn't actually a rootkit -- and the criminal group responsible for that software was taken down by the FBI in 2009.